# In django-taggit, is there a way to get all tags assoicated to a model?

Tags: django, model, tags, django-taggit

I know how to get all tags, but let's say the tags are connected to lots of different models.

Somehow I just want to extra the tags that is attached to a model not ALL tags.

Is this possible?

I know that I can do it in reverse, get the model then get all the tags, but I have LOTS rows in that model and if I try it this way, I have to get all rows then loop through all rows to get queryset of the tags

But all I want is get all the tags attached to the model and count the tags.  I do not require to know which row of the model is using this tag.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you ever found out the answer ? For a week I've been trying to figure out why following won't work (plant is the tagged model, need is the Tag.objects.all() , Tag being imported from taggit.models):
{% for need in needs %}
  {% for plant in need.plants.all %}
    {{ plant.species }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}'

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call tags on Model class itself. Try with below code

```
tags = YourModel.tags.all()
tags = tags.annotate(tag_count=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items'))
```